# Display files from another directory with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, file

I have moved all files from a project that should be accessible from outside to a single `public` directory - so that instead of blacklisting directories that must remain hidden, I could whitelist accessible ones.

However I cannot force apache to rewrite this kind of urls:

- www.example.com/images/flower.jpg

to fetch

- `<DOCUMENT ROOT>`/**public**/images/flower.jpg

Only rational solution I came up with was something among those lines:

```
RewriteCond public\/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f #if a file exists in the public dir,...
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]               #display it
```

Unsurprisingly, it does not work, more precisely, the `RewriteCond` part, I can't get it to match.

I am completely at loss, could someone help?

As a side question, how do you debug `.htaccess` configurations? I can't fix the problem if I don't know what and where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test for an existing file with `-f`, you need to provide an absolute file system path like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Otherwise use `-F` to do the check via a subrequest:

```
RewriteCond public%{REQUEST_URI} -F
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```